# Linking against DLL with no __imp__ exports

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, declspec

I'm trying to link my project with a DLL (let's call it A.DLL) and I'm getting the unresolved external symbol `__imp__?func@@YA_JXZ`. I "dumpbin /exports"ed the DLL and the lib and I saw only `?func@@YAJXZ.`

So I would be very grateful if some1 could explain 1)why the difference in postfix in fund's decorated name 2) why is there no `__imp__func` name in the DLL nor in the Lib file for the dereferencing function?

Comment: Normally the __imp__ should not be present in the DLL, only in the static import lib. And the reason name is different might be because it's not a function, it's a function pointer.

Comment: __imp__func also does not appear in lib. And it is a function declared in the header file.

Comment: Getting the `__imp_` export requires declaring the function with the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute.  Looks like this DLL was built with a .def file instead, it is not entirely uncommon.  You avoid this error by fixing the declaration on the client code side and *not* declare it `__declspec(dllimport)`.  All and all, something pretty wonky with the .h file you are using.  We can't see it.

Comment: I will try it, but the function is declared with declspec export/import macro. I just found out though that the dll was probably compiled in gnat, which means that probably mingw was used. It also may have consequences, no?